# Get specific data from another table using foreign key in Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

I a new Livewire user and I want to fetch a specific name from the User table using the foreign key of the user in my Blog table. I'm unsure of how to put code in the `render()` and Blade template. I've seen something like this: `{{ blogs->id->name }}`. How can I come up with a solution?

**User table**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Blog table**

```
Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('heading')->nullable();
    $table->text('paragraph');
    $table->text('featured_img');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**in User model declared**

```
public function blogs() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blogs::class);
}
```

**in Blog model declared**

```
public function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**render() method in Blogs class**

```
public function render()
{
    $blogs = Blogs::where('user_id', Auth::id())->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(3);
    $user = User::where('id', Auth::id())->get();

    return view('livewire.admin.blogs', [
        'blogs' => $blogs,
        'user' => $user
    ])->layout('layouts.admin');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already know the user and want to return all the blog posts for that specific user? If that is the case you can do the following with the relationships you have defined. I'm also presuming you want the blog posts of the logged in user.

```php
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.admin.blogs', [
        // No need to add the posts here, get them from the user model
        'user' => auth()->user(),
    ])->layout('layouts.admin');
}
```

Then inside your blade to loop over the blog posts for the user:

```php
<p>The blog posts for {{ $user->name }}</p>
@foreach ($user->blogs()->paginate(3) as $post)
<h1>{{ $post->title }}</h1>
<p>{{ $post->heading }}</p>
@endforeach
```

#### Update to fetch user

If you want to fetch the user for a specific blog post you can then use the user relationship on the blog model itself.

```php
// From the Blog model access the User relationship and return 
// the `name` for the specific user who created the blog post.
$post->user->name
```

Comment: Thank you Sir @Leon for the quick answer.. But  I want to return the name of the user who created the blog. So in my blog schema user has the foreign key id "user_id"  but I don't know how to fetch the name of the user_id in the User schema.

Comment: @nhaj0415 I updated my answer for you to access the user from the blog model.